# How to uninstall DeskTime from ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I download "desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb" file form DeskTime official website and install. Now, I am trying to uninstall desktime from my ubuntu but I didn't find it on Ubuntu software.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i  desktime` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1266339/edit).

Comment: As you installed it from the .deb, open that .deb up with gdebi and it will have the option to uninstall it. If you don't have the .deb anymore, just go ahead and download it again.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt purge desktime-linux
```

From the comment of @N0bert, if you `dpkg -l | grep -i  desktime`, you will get something like `ii  desktime-linux`. So just *purge* that file